# How do I map dependent subscriptions into a list of objects with data combined from each subscription?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs

**How do I map dependent subscriptions into a list of objects with data combined from each subscriptions return result?**

I have an Observable containing an array of objects which gets returned from an API call, lets call them users.

I have a second observable which fetches another array of objects and returns an observable collection. Lets say this one is named messages.

I have the need to grab an auth token via xhr, use the auth token to fetch the users, use the user ID to fetch the messages for each user.

The desired result of this would look similar to:

`const returnValue = [{ userId: 1, messages: [{...}]}];`

I have a setup which looks like this

```
users$.pipe(flatMap(user => { 
    this._userMessageService.getMessages$(user.id).subscribe(messages => {
    user.messages = messages;
    return user;
}))).subscribe((usersWithMessages) => console.log({usersWithMessages}));
```

As I am sure many of you can see, this will return a user with undefined messages. My question is how to handle multiple dependent async calls which return objects of users with messages using RXJS.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called [combination](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/) in rxJs

There are different strategies on how to implement Observable combinations (as described on the above link)

an example is a `combineLatest`, which has the following description: When any observable emits a value, emit the last emitted value from each.

I would suggest you change your message query to a call that can retrieve all the user messages

```
this.users$ = this.userService.getUsers(); // my guess
this.messages$ = this._userMessageService.getUserMessages$(); // 

combineLatest(this.users$, this.messages$).subscribe(
  ([users, messages]) => {

    console.log('users', users);
    console.log('messages', messages);

    //logic to set messages on the user objects goes here
  }
);
```

hopefully this sets you on the right track